# Split Pushed Elements Into A Javascript Empty Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an empty array called result[].  A user then clicks a link which calls a function called getId() that passes the clicked id to check if it matches the id in another array called productsArray[].

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="abc" onClick="getId(this.id)">Jackets</a>

var productsArray = [
    {id:0, title:"Product A",description:"description 0"}, 
    {id:0, title:"Product B",description:"description 1"}, 
    {id:2, title:"Product C",description:"description 2",}, 
    {id:0, title:"Product D",description:"description 3",},  
    {id:4, title:"Product A",description:"description 4",}, 
    {id:5, title:"Product A",description:"description 5",}
],
result = [];
```

If the user clicks the Jackets link (which has an id of 0) the 3 items in the productsArray, will get returned: Product A, B and D.

The code I have to achieve this actually works:

```
var output;
var container;

for(key in productsArray) { 

    if (productsArray[key].id == id) { 
       result.push(productsArray[key].title, productsArray[key].description); 
    }
}

container = document.getElementById('content');
output=result;
container.innerHTML=output;

<div id="content"></div>
```

But the problem is that ALL the data is assigned to the result[] key index:

For example:

```
[0]Produduct A title
[1]Product B title
[2]Product C title
```

What I would like to achieve a way of splitting up the data along the lines of the following:

```
output+= result[0].title + result[0].description
```

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: You have to loop over the results array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the result and the wanted keys of the product.

```js
function getId(id) {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = productsArray
        .filter(function (product) {
            return product.id == id;
        })
        .map(function (product) {
            return ['title', 'description']
                .map(function (key) { return product[key]; })
                .join(' ');
        })
        .join('<br>');
}

var productsArray = [{ id: 0, title: "Product A", description: "description 0" }, { id: 0, title: "Product B", description: "description 1" }, { id: 2, title: "Product C", description: "description 2" }, { id: 0, title: "Product D", description: "description 3" }, { id: 4, title: "Product A", description: "description 4" }, { id: 5, title: "Product A", description: "description 5" }];
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void 0" onclick="getId(0)">Jackets</a>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign a variable that takes value of title and description and then push that value to array. like below code

```
function getId(id){
var output;
var container;
for(key in productsArray) { 
 if (productsArray[key].id == id) { 
newObj= "" ; // assign to blank
newObj = productsArray[key].title +" "+ productsArray[key].description; //assign as per you need the format
result.push(newObj);  // push it to array
    }
}

container = document.getElementById('content');
output=result;
container.innerHTML=output;}
```